# What happen if i use ruby version 2.5.1 with rails version 2.3.18?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.5

What happen if i use ruby version `2.5.1` with rails version `2.3.18` ?

I had rails application built on rails `2.3.18` and ruby `1.9.2p320`,
I want to upgrade version of **ruby only** not the rails is it possible ?

What are the challenges i have to face with this ?

Comment: It might be worth clarifying what a 'credible and/or official source' would look like, as a direct answer from a Rails core team member apparently isn't it. The official-official answer is "that version of Rails is extremely old and completely unsupported; don't use it" -- see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html

Comment: I wonder why you want to run a five years old version of Rails with well known and easy to exploit [security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-3482/) with an up-to-date version of Ruby? Why don't you follow the recommended update path? IMHO updating the Rails app is way more important than using the latest version of Ruby.

Answer (score 8):

GitHub maintain [a public fork](https://github.com/github/rails) that has branches for older Rails versions, with various changes, that they've been running over time. For some time, they were running older Rails releases on newer Ruby versions than they were originally supported on, so you might find some useful hints around what needs backporting there. They haven't used 2.3 for a few years now, though, so at best it will make *less* work.

In general, Ruby versions make few incompatible changes, but with a codebase the size and variety of Rails, most of those few changes do hit somewhere. This seems like a bad idea to me: any security fixes in newer Ruby versions, for example, will be vastly outweighed by the known vulnerabilities in such an old Rails release.

If you're doing this because your application uses the system Ruby and you're upgrading/replacing the OS, I would instead suggest using rbenv / chruby / ruby-build / ruby-install to install the old version for this app.

It should go without saying that running such an old Rails version is highly discouraged, and exposing it to the Internet is outright dangerous -- but I'll say it anyway.

[Rails LTS](https://railslts.com/) apparently provides a service backporting security fixes to Rails 2.3, which may make it slightly safer. They also seem to [currently support running Rails 2.3 with Ruby 2.3](https://makandracards.com/railslts/47192-ruby-2-3-support); while that's not 2.5, it might get you closer, or be good enough.